# Kubuntu 23.10 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter not working

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb, kubuntu, adapter

I have Kubuntu 23.10 installed, apparently the drivers for mt7601u are installed
But when you plug in the USB board (Ralink MT7601U (148f:7601) Wi-Fi adapter) it does not incorporate it for the Wifi network connection.
I read all the background information but they didn't work for me. t.ly/mTDpy and other.
Any ideas?

> lsb_release -a
> No LSB modules are available.
> Distributor ID: Ubuntu
> Description:    Ubuntu 23.10
> Release:    23.10
> Codename:   mantic

> lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 017: ID 0bda:8172 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8191SU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 002 Device 016: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
```

> inxi -Fxxxrz

```
Network:
Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
vendor: ASUSTeK P8 series driver: r8169 v: kernel pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s
lanes: 1 port: e000 bus-ID: 03:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:8168 class-ID: 0200
IF: enp3s0 state: down mac: <filter>
Device-2: Ralink MT7601U Wireless Adapter driver: N/A type: USB rev: 2.0
speed: 480 Mb/s lanes: 1 bus-ID: 2-1.5:16 chip-ID: 148f:7601 class-ID: 0000
serial: <filter>
```

> ls -l  /sys/bus/usb/drivers/ |grep mt7601u
> drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 ene 12 21:31 mt7601u

> $ rfkill list

```
1: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

> $ip link

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether e0:3f:49:56:11:13 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: wlx00231301e685: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:23:13:01:e6:85 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

> sudo dmesg |grep mt

```
    [12044.107310] mt7601u: probe of 2-1.5:1.0 failed with error -22
    [15475.275479] mt7601u 2-1.5:1.0: ASIC revision: 76010001 MAC revision: 76010500
    [15475.298829] mt7601u 2-1.5:1.0: Firmware Version: 0.1.00 Build: 7640 Build time: 201302052146____
    [15475.699693] mt7601u 2-1.5:1.0: Error: your device needs default EEPROM file and this driver doesn't support
```

Comment: The easy way is to find a different USB adapter that is supported by the kernel, see https://github.com/morrownr/USB-WiFi  There are quite a few cheap mt7601u devices that have that issue.  I have a fix but it really isn't worth the time

Comment: Now I check the link. Many thanks.

Comment: I will chech that link. Thank